# Can I provide bytes to Radare to be disassembled?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, radare2

Let's say I want to check [this guys work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27265685/124486). He says that he is getting

```
8d 15 c8 90 04 08       lea    0x80490c8,%edx
ba c8 90 04 08          mov    $0x80490c8,%edx
```

Is there an easy way with Radare to disassemble an user-provide byte-sequence like `8d 15 c8 90 04 08`

Comment: Why not just use Capstone?

Comment: yeah use rasm2 -a arch -b bits -d "bytes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `pad` command from inside radare2:

```
[0x00000000]> pa?
|Usage: pa[ed] [hex|asm]  assemble (pa) disasm (pad) esil (pae) from hexpairs

[0x00000000]> pad 8d 15 c8 90 04 08
lea edx, [rip + 0x80490c8]

[0x00000000]> pad 8d 15 c8 90 04 08 ba c8 90 04 08
lea edx, [rip + 0x80490c8]
mov edx, 0x80490c8
```

Or using `rasm2` utility from the radare2 toolkit:

```
$ rasm2 -d '8d 15 c8 90 04 08'
lea edx, [0x80490c8]
```

Comment: very cool, thanks! follow-up: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18007/22669

Answer (score 2):

use rasm2 - a x86,arm,ppc,whatever   -b 16,32,64  -d "de ad d0 0d"