# Printing bytecode in bytes given a string of assembly for Radare to disassemble?

Tags: assembly, x86, radare2, x86-64

[Megabeets](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/18698/megabeets) determined [in this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18008/22669) that depending on `asm.bits` Radare may show either

```
lea edx, [0x80490c8]         (asm.bits=32)
lea edx, [rip + 0x80490c8]   (asm.bits=64)
```

If I want to see what the byte-code would look like for `lea edx, [0x80490c8]` in x86_64, how would I go about getting that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no `lea edx, [0x80490c8]` for 64-bits addressing modes. Since, afaik, in all 64-bits addressing modes `lea` is a register relative opcode.

> **LEA - Load Effective Address**
>   Computes the effective address of the second operand (the
>   source operand) and stores it in the first operand (destination
>   operand). The source operand is a memory address (offset part)
>   specified with one of the processors addressing modes; the destination
>   operand is a general-purpose register.
>
> Source: Intel® [64 and IA-32 Architectures
>   Software Developer’s Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)

---

Anyway, if you want to know the bytecodes that represent an instruction using radare2 you can use the `pa` command.

In 32-bits mode it'll look like this:

```
[0x00000000]> e asm.bits=32
[0x00000000]> pa lea edx, [0x80490c8]
8d15c8900408
[0x00000000]> pad 8d15c8900408
lea edx, [0x80490c8]
```

In 64-bits mode it'll look like this:

```
[0x00000000]> e asm.bits=64
[0x00000000]> pa lea edx, [0x80490c8]
488d15c8900408
[0x00000000]> pad 488d15c8900408
lea rdx, [rip + 0x80490c8]
```

You can see that radare2 knows that `lea edx, [0x80490c8]` can't be expressed in 64bits so it uses a RIP relative expression.

Answer (score 0):

32

```
radare2  -a x86 -b 32 -c "wa lea edx,[0x80490c8] ; pd 1 ; exit()" -
Written 6 byte(s) (lea edx,[0x80490c8]) = wx 8d15c8900408
            0x00000000      8d15c8900408   lea edx, [0x80490c8]
 -- Are you a wizard?
[0x00000000]> q
```

64

```
radare2  -a x86 -b 64 -c "wa lea edx,[rip+0x80490c8] ; pd 1 ; exit()" -
Written 7 byte(s) (lea edx,[rip+0x80490c8]) = wx 488d98c8900408
            0x00000000      488d98c89004.  lea rbx, [rax + 0x80490c8]
 -- SHALL WE PLAY A GAME?
[0x00000000]> q
```